# Is there a way to delete several issues at once in YouTrack 7?

Tags: devops, issue-tracking, youtrack, kanban

I'm working with **Youtrack 7** and I have several old issues which I want to delete. I can only delete issues one by one and it's frustrating. I can select issues but there is no button to delete them:
[image: panel]

I have role of Project Admin and Developer but I can only remove them by selecting them one by one:
[image: issue]

Is there a way to do it faster??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is.

To delete several issues at once

1. Select them
2. Open command window the highlighted button. Or hit `Ctrl + Alt + J`.
3. Type `delete` and hit enter

[image]